# Install LARAVEL 5 Locally Same as Share Hosting Directory (Deploy L5 Share Hosting Solution)

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I am trying to find the way to organise my Laravel Application same as share hosting directory.

Example inside "**server**" folder

1.Install fresh laravel application

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel main-app --prefer-dist
```

2.Move "Public" directory up and next to main-app folder.Rename to public_html

3.Inside public_html folder also create new "app" folder to keep all the files like inside index.php

Summary

`server
│

└───main-app
│    │   app
│    │   bootstrap 
│    │   ......
│
└───public_html
    │    app
    │     │─── index.php
    │`

This is what I need to do.But I couldn't make this work!
Each time I try to run artisan I got

> chdir() no such file or directory (errno 2)

With Laravel 4 I was able to edit path.php and thats it.But L5 looks like one step back!

I already tried to extend Application.php class but unfortunately didn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is Solution !**

**1.Create MyApp.php class inside app folder to extend Applicaton.php class**

```
<?php 
namespace App;

class MyApp  extends \Illuminate\Foundation\Application
{
    public function publicPath()
    {
        return $this->basePath.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'/../public_html/app';
    }
}
```

**2.Inside bootsrap/app use own class**

Make sure comment out old one! , you don't need anymore

```
// $app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
//     realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
// );

$app = new App\MyApp(
realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
);
```

**3.Make changes inside server.php to target index.php**

```
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/../public_html/app'.$uri)) {
      return false;
}


require_once __DIR__.'/../public_html/app/index.php';
```

**4.Make changes inside index.php**

```
require __DIR__.'/../../main-app/bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

and

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../main-app/bootstrap/app.php';
```

**DONE**

Now artisan working and Index.php live same as share hosting!

`server
│

└───main-app
│    │   app
│    │   bootstrap 
│    │   ......
│
└───public_html
    │    app
    │     │─── index.php
    │`

Comment: Do you have `ssh` access? If yes, you must symlink `public` to `public_html`.

Comment: Yes I have ssh access and I am committing my updates via git without using symlink.As a first step, inside temp folder on server pull git then copy all files to main-app! This way no corrupted files!

Comment: The best solution is described there in the selected answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28433715/specify-a-different-public-path